# display data in real time coming from sqlite database in html without refresh page

Tags: jquery, ajax, sqlite, flask

I am new in web dev and i have to create a real time dashboards, i have sqlite database which receive data from device, and i use flask in order to retrieve data to display it.my probleme was i can't use socketio in order to refresh my data without refresh page, so it will be useful way with ajax and jquery, can anyone can help me please .

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time
# Retrieve data from database
@app.route("/get_data")
def getData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('sagemdb')
    curs=conn.cursor()

    DateTimee = datetime.time()
    memUsage = 0
    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM STBdata"):
        DateTimee = str(row[0])
        memUsage = row[1]
    conn.close()
    return DateTimee, memUsage
# main route 
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    DateTimee1, memUsage1 = getData()
    templateData = {
        'time': DateTimee1,
        'memUsage': memUsage1,
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=4000)

**HTML Code : 

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

    </head>
    <body>
<h3>{{time}}</h3>
<h3>{{memUsage}}</h3>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**